# Timeout doesn't time out

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of functions in a javascript object. Here is one of them:

```
addImage: function(evt) {
        var file = evt.target.files[0];
        /* Only process image files.*/
        if(file.type.match('image.*')) {
            /*Add image to FileReader object*/
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            /*Add image to local storage */
            reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
                return function(e) {
                    localStorage.setItem(underlayer.url, e.target.result);
                    //add image
                    underlayer.setImage();
                    underlayer.setPosition();
                    setTimeout(underlayer.setHeight(), 5000);

                };
            })(file);
        }
    },
```

I want underlayer.setHeight() to trigger after a delay it's necessary because it reads the height of an image that is loaded into the local storage, and that takes a couple of milliseconds.However, underlayer.setHeight is triggered emidiately, not with a delay.

Comment: As i understand it, you shouldn't use a timeout for that but the onload event of added image

Answer (score 8):

By putting `()` after `setHeight`, you are CALLING the function, and passing its RETURN VALUE to `setTimeout`. This is clearly not what you're trying to do.

Remove the `()` and it should work fine.

EDIT: Forgot about context. `setTimeout(function() {underlayer.setHeight();},5000);` is probably your best bet, then.

Comment: Ah, that's true. Forgot about that XD

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your `setTimeout` code.

```
setTimeout(function(){underlayer.setHeight()},5000);
```